# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobListingDetails Exception

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a table that is on a azure blob storage via pyspark and the below exception is raised even though I have added the below jars in the pyspark --jars.

```
azure-storage-2.0.0.jar
hadoop-azure-2.7.0.jar
```

Exception:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.showString.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobListingDetails
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobListingDetails
```

Any idea as which specific jar needs to be added to resolve the issue and read azure tables in spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is that as below.

1. Please download the jar files of the newest version of [Azure Storage Java Client](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage/5.0.0) & [Hadoop Azure Support](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure/2.7.3) instead of their old version.
2. Check whether the path of these jars were added into the `SPARK_CLASSPATH` environment variable in the `conf/spark-env` file, or you can programmatically add the jar path via code `SparkContext.addJar("Path to jar created from maven [hint: mvn package]")`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: adding the jars to a spark.conf file worked out . `spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/xyz/jars/*`
also, updated the jars to latest version